# Flutter Main ListView Won't Respond to Mouse Scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

this: model.sideList.elementAt(model.getIndex).screen is a ListView with a scrollbar as a parent widget.
Thanks.

I tried removing the Scrollbar widget, wrapping my shown SizedBox of the screen with a SingleChildScrollView, removing scrollControllers.
`

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      SideMenu(context1: context),
      SizedBox(
        width: size.width > 1000 ? size.width * 0.825 : size.width * 0.775,
        child: model.sideList.elementAt(model.getIndex).screen,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

`

Comment: What Do you want to be scrollable in this widget

Comment: Did you add  `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, shrinkWrap: true,` in your ListView?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.